# Clicked button shows text and images

Tags: android, button, kotlin

I can't cope with the quite simple task of displaying text and images after clicking a button. I have searched many guides on this topic, but still my application stops working and Logcat does not show red errors. I want the text and images to be displayed after pressing the button. I do it on Navigation Drawer Activity, I added to **MainActivity.kt**:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private lateinit var appBarConfiguration: AppBarConfiguration

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val toolbar: Toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar)
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar)


    val btn1=findViewById(R.id.btn_ghtstg1) as Button;
    val show_text_ghtstg1=findViewById(R.id.text_ghtstg1) as TextView;
    val show_text_ghtstg2=findViewById(R.id.text_ghtstg2) as TextView;
    val show_text_ghtstg3=findViewById(R.id.text_ghtstg3) as TextView;
    val show_image_ghtstg1=findViewById(R.id.image_ghtstg1) as ImageView;
    val show_image_ghtstg2=findViewById(R.id.image_ghtstg2) as ImageView;
    val show_image_ghtstg3=findViewById(R.id.image_ghtstg3) as ImageView;
    btn1.setOnClickListener {
        show_text_ghtstg1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        show_text_ghtstg2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        show_text_ghtstg3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        show_image_ghtstg1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        show_image_ghtstg2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        show_image_ghtstg3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    val btn2=findViewById(R.id.btn_htetev) as Button;
    val show_text_htetev1=findViewById(R.id.text_htetev1) as TextView;
    val show_image_htetev1=findViewById(R.id.image_htetev1) as ImageView;
    btn2.setOnClickListener {
        show_text_htetev1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        show_image_htetev1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
```

On Common Attributes in the **OnClick** position, I entered **btn1** (for the first button) and **btn2** (for the second button). All texts and images in **fragment_game.xml** have the visibility value set to **GONE**.

Button1 and Button2 from **fragment_game.xml**:

```
                <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_ghtstg1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:onClick="btn1"
                android:text="@string/button_ghtstg" />

                <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_htetev"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:onClick="btn2"
                android:text="@string/button_htetev" />
```

Full fragment_game.XML for Rander Gabriel:

```
    <ScrollView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_game"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_ghtstg1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/button_ghtstg" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_ghtstg1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/text_ghtstg1"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_ghtstg1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/house_to_ventti" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_ghtstg2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/text_ghtstg2"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_ghtstg2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/city_abadoned_house" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_ghtstg3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/text_ghtstg3"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_ghtstg3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/abandoned_house_to_home"
            tools:visibility="gone" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_ghtstg4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/text_ghtstg4"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_htetev"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/button_htetev" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_htetev1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/text_htetev1"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_htetev1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/experimentalproperties" />

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call setOnClickListener() you don't need to specify the onClick attribute on the XML tags.

The onClick attribute expects a method name that should be in the Activity classe and that matched the View.OnClickListener signature. Try to remove that attr from your XML tags and It should work

Comment: I tried to do it before, after removing btn1 and btn2 from the onClick attribute the application still doesn't work.

Comment: Can you add your Full .XML file to the question?